# 'A Minor' songs suitable for a beginner that include lead and rhytmn parts

Tags: scales, rhythm, beginner

I'm a relative beginner to the guitar, and I'm looking to learn a few songs to compliment what I'm learning with my guitar tutor at the moment.

Right now we're working on House of the Rising Sun (in the key of A Minor), and we're using the A Minor scale to play lead parts over it in place of vocals (ie using the scale to recreate the vocals) which is a fun way to learn. I'm enjoying that.

I would like to have one or two other songs to practice between lessons that are complimentary to this, and so I wondered if the good people of Stack Exchange could recommend any songs in the key of A Minor that I could also learn with both a rhythm and a lead guitar section.

My taste in music revolves around the whole kerrang tv era (pop punk, foo fighters, all that good stuff) as well as Brit Pop (Blur, Pulp, Radiohead if they count as britpop) and I like anything acoustic Jack Johnson and similar.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Songs don't *have* to be in Am. Any song in a minor key can be transposed into Am, especially if you're going to play rather than sing, which is where transposition can cause problems. So - use any minor song. Your tutor now has at least a1,000 to choose from to transpose...  That apart, lists are not part of what we do here, sorry!

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm aware of transposing but I'm pretty new to the guitar thing, so not confident enough to do that just yet! Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's just one place your tutor earns his money!

Comment: Actually, he teaches me for free :) but he's going to teach me how to transpose House of the rising sun once we've finished learning it.

Comment: Suggest he starts with some 12 bar blues transpositions.

Comment: Babe I'm gonna leave you by Zep